# How to fix: Doctrine not returning properly

Tags: javascript, symfony

I want to make dynamic delete posts function but the result is error because value is null.

**Controller**

```
/**
  * @Route("/posts/delete/{id}", name="delete_post", methods={"DELETE"})
  */
  public function deletePost($id, LoggerInterface $logger)
  {

    $post=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Article::class)->find($id);

    if(!$post)
    {
        $this->addFlash(
            'notice',
            'Something went wrong'
        );
        $logger->info($id);
    }
    else
    {

        $entityManager=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->remove($post);
        $entityManager->flush();
        $entityManager->clear();
    }

    $response=new Response();
    return($response);
  }
```

**JS**

```
const articles = document.getElementById("articles");

if (articles) {
 articles.addEventListener("click", e => {
  if (e.target.className === "btn btn-danger delete-article") {
  if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
    const id = e.target.getAttribute("data-id");

    fetch("/posts/delete/${id}", {
      method: "DELETE"
    }).then(res => window.location.reload());
  }
 }
 });
}
```

**Twig**

```
<table border="1" id="articles">
        <tr>
            <th class="pt">Post title</th>
            <th class="pe">Edit</th>
            <th class="pd">Delete</th>
        </tr>
        {% for article in articles %}
            <tr>
                <td class="title">{{ article.title }}</td>
                <td class="edit">
                    <a href="{{ path('posts_editor', {'id':article.id}) }}" class="btn btn-primary edit-article">
                        <img src="{{ asset('images/edit.png') }}" class="image">
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td class="delete">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger delete-article" data-id="{{article.id}}">
                        <img src="{{ asset('images/delete.png') }}" class="image">
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

I was doing it with video tutorial and I don't know what is wrong on video this code was working but when I wrote it I just got an error below

**Error**

> EntityManager#remove() expects parameter 1 to be an entity object, NULL given.

Hope anyone can help me, I am really getting frustrated because of it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixed**

Just had to change this

```
fetch("/posts/delete/${id}", {
  method: "DELETE"
}).then(res => window.location.reload());
```

In this

```
fetch("/posts/delete/" + id, {
      method: "POST"
    }).then(res => window.location.reload());
```

Now it's deleting posts properly

Comment: The problem is with the quotes around "/posts/delete/${id}", for ${id} to be interpreted and replaced correctly you need the " ` " character as a quotation instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's clearly said that **$post** is null, so in this case, you can 
dump this two variable and I hope you will figure it out what's going on

```
dump($id);
dump($post);
exit
```

you can the see doc [Doctrine Removing entities](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-objects.html#removing-entities)

**updated:**

in your code, you are always sending a response, you need to update response to specific with success or error code by default it is sending 200 code and also you to need to update your code

```
public function deletePost($id, LoggerInterface $logger)
{

$post=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Article::class)->find($id);

    if(!$post)
    {
        $this->addFlash(
            'notice',
            'Something went wrong'
        );
        $logger->info($id);

        exit() your code here
        or throw an exception here
    }

    try {
        //remove entity here 
        $response = new Response(
            'Content',
            Response::HTTP_OK,
            ['content-type' => 'text/html']
        );

        return $response;
    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        $response = new Response(
            $exception->getMessage(),
            Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
            ['content-type' => 'text/html']
            );
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried dump. The problem is that profiler shows: "No content was dumped.", so I decided to ask for help because I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: when you click delete then check profiler in ajax option and also stop redirect after success so then u can see the response.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Just had to add variable in other way in JS file